# best approach to linking two c libraries with mangled symbols

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I have two c libraries I'm trying to link, for example in `liba` there is a function

```c
int foo_a(int a) { return a + 1; }
```

which is called from `libb` but though a redefined but fully equivalent symbol, for example

```c
int b = foo_b(1);
```

linking these results in missing symbols as `foo_b` should actually be `foo_a`. Assuming I can't modify or recompile the libraries, would the best approach be to write a wrapper, something like `wrapper.h`

```c
int foo_b(int a) { foo_a(a); }
```

Or is there a better (maybe more performant) approach of just adding symbol translation (I'm assuming just modifying the header of liba is not enough)?

Answer (score 0):

in ld linker script add

```
PROVIDE(foo_b = foo_a);
```

Comment: Thanks, I added `PROVIDE(dgemm_ = dgemm);` to the default link script, but this does not seem to resolve the symbol

`ld:link.ld:346: undefined symbol dgemm referenced in expression`

`nm -S libblas.a | grep dgemm >
0000000000000000 I __imp_dgemm
0000000000000000 T dgemm`

`nm -S libdmumps.a | grep dgemm > U dgemm_`

Is there something more required maybe?